# Running python code created in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, python-3, qgis-python-console

I'm using QGIS 3.4 and Python 3.7.0 on Windows 7.

From the Python console of QGIS, I created a test script ("test.py") which contains the following line:

```
print('Hello)
```

and this is saved in C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\test.py

I want to run this script from outside QGIS.

I tried opening "python-qgis.bat" which I found in C:\OSGeo4W64\bin, and typed:

`test.py`

but got an error saying [NameError: name 'test' is not defined].

The code itself works fine from QGIS, but because I want to run it from outside QGIS, do I need all the import... etc at the beginning of the script?

What do I need to do?

Comment: print is a builtin so you don't need imports but you will eventually as you start using QGIS objects, try using the full path to the file C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\test.py and see if that helps but I suspect the problem is the python console is looking for an object called 'test' with 'py' method, have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17247471/how-to-run-a-python-script-from-idle-interactive-shell about calling a script from a python console.

Comment: You should get a syntax error, due to the missing quote.

Answer (score 2):

As commented by @MichaelStimson:

> print is a builtin so you don't need imports but you will eventually
>   as you start using QGIS objects, try using the full path to the file
>   C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\test.py and see if that helps but I suspect the
>   problem is the python console is looking for an object called 'test'
>   with 'py' method, have a read of
>   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17247471/how-to-run-a-python-script-from-idle-interactive-shell
>   about calling a script from a python console.